# In Azure, starting an appService does not execute Startup

Tags: c#, azure, startup

I'm seeing a problem with all our ASP.NET web API projects that we deployed to Azure. The symptom is that when we start the appService, it starts and says it did so successfully. But none of the things that are configured in Startup happen until we try to call one of its endpoints or browse to its swagger page.

For instance, in one, we have a HostedService that connects to our SignalR hub. The hosted service starts up and connects once the Startup methods execute.

But just starting the App Service in Azure portal doesn't kick off the Startup methods, and so Azure says it's running, but it's not connected to SignalR and therefore is not listening for events.

The code I used to create the app's host is this:

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog(ConfigureLogger)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
         .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
         {
             if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
             {
                 var builtConfig = config.Build();
             }
         });
```

Is this a known behavior? Is there something wrong with the above code that is causing the Startup code to not execute until first use of the swagger or endpoint?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why `UseStartup<T>`? The default is `webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();`.

Comment: Sorry. This is in a library so that all our apps use the same means of creating the host. There are some proprietary stuff I removed about keys and stuff.

Comment: Well, if you add a `Console.WriteLine` in the `StartUp` method, do you see it when you run the app, without sending a request to an endpoint?

Comment: No. Startup does nothing until request is sent to the endpoint. That also means the first call to that endpoint after "starting the app service" takes a long time because its doing all its startup processing. It's then that the log stream posts the " A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X" startup message and all that. Literally, starting the app service causes no logs in the app services' log stream. Only when the endpoint is hit.

Comment: That is really weird. I just made an empty `webapi` project, put a log message in `StartUp` and it prints it.

Comment: To be clear, this only happens when deployed in Azure. When I run locally, it all works normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your app has `Always On` enabled in Azure?

If you go to application settings, there is an always on setting:

[image: azure always on]

Comment: This solved it! We had this turned off and was using health check instead to keep it from going idle. But apparently, health check was enough to get it fully up after a restart.